# love2d key detected as being pressed more than once

Tags: lua, love2d

so i was making a game, and ran into a bug where `love.keyboard.isDown()` detected a key being pressed more than once

code:

```
function love.update(dt)
    if love.keyboard.isDown("escape") and Menu == false then
        Menu = true
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown("escape") and Menu == true then
        Menu = false
    end
```

when pressing the `esc` key, the game goes crazy switching between the menu and the gameplay. is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`love.keyboard.isDown(key)` checks whether a key is held down, which is usually a few frames even for a short press.

Take a look at https://love2d.org/wiki/love.keyboard.isDown.

In your case you probably want the `love.keypressed` event, which only triggers once (https://love2d.org/wiki/love.keypressed)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this behaviour is wanted and sometimes not.
If you dont want this behaviour simply use...

```
local debug = false

function love.keyreleased(key)                                                                                                                                      
    if key == 'd' then                                                                                                                                              
      if debug then debug = false else debug = true end                                                                                                             
    end                                                                                                                                                             
    if key == 'r' then                                                                                                                                              
      love.event.quit('restart')                                                                                                                                    
    end                                                                                                                                                             
end
```

Behaviour:

1. Push the key <kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>R</kbd> => Nothing happens
2. Release the key <kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>R</kbd> => Function is triggered

Look: https://love2d.org/wiki/love.keyreleased